# iPhone images display

Tags: image, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to know if there is any way to append something like white border around iPad image thumbnails without too much performance issues?

Something like in XHTML\CSS where you get Polaroid like appearance.I think you may have got faint idea.

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way would be to draw a frame around your images if they're all of the same size (your thumbnails).